# JS always returing the first value of 0 in an INPUT Range. After the first attempt it returns the correct value

Tags: javascript

I am using an Input range slider and JS is giving the default value of 0 first and after that it gives the correct value.
So when I go to change the textContent to the value of the range its always a 0. After the first attempt the value is correct.

I have tried event listener to be "change" instead of "click". The result stays the same.

What am I missing?

JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5g78a4qL/

HTML
'''

Select your age

```
            <input type="range" min="1" max="100" id="myRange" class="rch-slider">'''
```

JS
'''let slider = document.getElementById("myRange");

let output = 0;
let personAge = 0;

document.querySelector('#myRange').addEventListener('click', function(event){

```
document.querySelector('#yourAge').textContent = "Your Age: ";

output = document.getElementById("value")

output.innerHTML = slider.value

slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
    personAge = Number(this.value);
}
```

})

document.querySelector('#myRange').addEventListener('click', function(event){
console.log(personAge);

})'''

Answer (score 0):

Try 'change' event listener instead of click...

```
document.querySelector('#myRange').addEventListener('change', function(event){

  document.querySelector('#yourAge').textContent = "Your Age: ";

  output = document.getElementById("value")

  output.innerHTML = slider.value

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
    personAge = Number(this.value);
  }
})
```

THE RANGE INPUT:

```
<input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="100" id="myRange" class="rch-slider">
```

Comment: event listener is still starts off being 0 when i change it from "click" to "change"

Comment: also add value="1" in your range input

Comment: I have added value "1". Didnt resolve the issue https://jsfiddle.net/5g78a4qL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="rch-age-section margin-sections">

            <div class="rch-age"> <span id="yourAge">Select your age</span> <span id="value"></span></div>

            <input type="range" min="1" max="100" id="myRange" class="rch-slider">
        </div>
<script>
let slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
let output = document.getElementById("value");
let personAge = 0;

document.querySelector('#myRange').addEventListener('click', 
function(event){

document.getElementById("yourAge").textContent = "Your Age: ";

output.textContent = slider.value

personAge = Number(slider.value);

    console.log(personAge);
})


</script>
```

Comment: event listener is still starts off being 0 when i change it from "click" to "change"

Comment: It now starts off with 1. So it's something to do with declaring the "personAge" in the beginning

Comment: my bad, I corrected

Comment: your code works but the number doesnt change while it is being dragged. I cant figure your why this is